# Как привязать span к правой части выпадающего окна?

Tags: html, css

Потому что в css `text-align: right;` не работает, а используя margin получается результат на фото ниже. Есть какая-то возможность это исправить?

css:

```
.gray {
 color: gray;
 margin-left: 3px;
}
.price {
  color: gray;
  /*text-align: right;*/
  margin-left: 145px;
}
```

html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox">Все курорты, Турция</li>
       <div>
       <hr>
       <h6 class="dropdown-header">Популярные курорты</h6>
       <hr>
       </div>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Аланья,<span class="gray">Турция</span><span class="price">от 18 963 р./чел.</span></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Анталья,<span class="gray">Турция</span><span class="price">от 19 311 р./чел.</span></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Белек,<span class="gray">Турция</span><span class="price">от 25 204 р./чел.</span></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Бодрум,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Кемер,<span class="gray">Турция</span><span class="price">от 16 102 р./чел.</span></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Мармарис,<span class="gray">Турция</span></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Сиде,<span class="gray">Турция</span><span class="price">от 20 660 р./чел.</span></li>
     </ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для адаптивности и гибкости в будущем, лучше использовать `flexbox` 
Вот пример:

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="left">
        <input type="checkbox"> Аланья,<span class="gray">Турция</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <span class="price">от 18 963 р./чел.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex   {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: я только начал писать и тут ты))